# Not Equal Operation is not working

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

1st Table : `center` (2 columns)

```
+-----------------------------------+
|id | company_name                  |
+-----------------------------------+ 
|2  | Skytel Outsourcing Pvt. Ltd.  |
+-----------------------------------+
```

2nd Table : `campaign_center` (3 columns)

```
+-------------------------------------+
|campaign_id |  Center_id  | sl_no    |
+-------------------------------------+ 
|Demo        |    2        | 2        |
+-------------------------------------+
|MyFootPath  |    2        | 3        |
+-------------------------------------+
```

When I execute this query it's working perfectly: (To find `center_id` and company name who's `campaignid` is `'Demo'`)

```
select center.id, center.company_name 
from center 
  inner join campaign_center 
  on center.id = campaign_center.center_id 
where campaign_center.campaign_id = 'Demo'
```

but again when i am trying to find those company who's `campaign_id` is not `'Demo'` it doesn't give correct output:

```
select center.id, center.company_name 
from center 
  inner join campaign_center 
  on center.id = campaign_center.center_id 
where campaign_center.campaign_id != 'Demo'
```

How do I get those ? Please help.

Comment: From what I can see, the second query output is entirely correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query will give you all companies that have (one or more) campaign centers with id different than `'Demo'`. But those that have a `'Demo'` and some other campaign id will still be included.

I guess that you want something different. To find those companies that none of their `campaign_id` is `'Demo'`. If so, you need an anti-semijoin (often called anti-join) which can be accomplished with either `NOT IN` or a `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` or a `NOT EXISTS` query:

```
SELECT c.id, c.company_name 
FROM center AS c
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM campaign_center AS cc 
        WHERE c.id = cc.center_id 
          AND cc.campaign_id = 'Demo'
      ) ;
```